# Is it possible to cc npcs by emptying their energy pool?

Tags: guild-wars

From DoA, I know that using Energy Surge on the same enemy too many times can result in damage loss because there's no more energy in their pool to burn. Aside from that, however, I haven't noticed much, if any, ability usage decrease in my general PvE as a result of lengthy fighting attrition.

Does energy pressure have any effect on enemy skill use, and can it be used to shut down key npcs, for example healers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to empty their mana pool. The [Famine farmer](http://pvx.wikia.com/wiki/Build:R/Me_Famine_Farmer) build relies on that.

However, there is a difference in NPC energy regen, which is another requirement for the Famine farm build to work: Whenever an NPC hits zero energy, they seem to gain back a small amount immediately. This must be the case because if a PC is already at zero energy and takes another energy loss effect, Famine and related effects do not trigger. You need to lose at least 1 energy for Famine to trigger. Since you can farm bosses with Famine, they either have very high energy regen or, as mentioned, they gain back some energy when they hit zero.

So yes, you can drain them to zero, but you will most likely not be able to suppress them from casting any spells for any stretch of time.